# Class 'Srmklive\PayPal\Facades\Paypal' not found in production

Tags: laravel, paypal, dependencies, laravel-forge

I am using a laravel paypal plugin called "srmklive/paypal". The plugin is worked in my local but not in the production server. When I check the logs it prompt me this error. This is the details of the server,

php version : 7.2
Laravel version : 5.8.8

Please help on this.

The logs show me this error :

```
production.ERROR: Class 'Srmklive\PayPal\Facades\Paypal' not found
{"exception":"[object](Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
Class 'Srmklive\\PayPal\\Facades\\Paypal' not found at /home/forge/pixerbear-api.tk/app/Http/Controllers/PaymentController.php:26)
```

Meanwhile my PaymentController :

```
use Auth;
use DB;
use App\Credit;
use App\Storage;
use App\Payment;
use App\ProviderStorage;
use App\UserCredit;
use Response;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Facades\Paypal;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Services\ExpressCheckout;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    private $provider;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->provider = new ExpressCheckout;
        $this->provider = PayPal::setProvider('express_checkout');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run `composer install` or equivalent on your production server in order to install the Composer package(s)?

Comment: @AkenRoberts I had run the `composer install` in my production server but still having the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a typo in the namespace here; `use Srmklive\PayPal\Facades\Paypal;`. It should be `use Srmklive\PayPal\Facades\PayPal;` (notice the uppercase `P`).